# How to fix the GeoDjango Tutorial?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, geodjango, spatialite

I'm trying to do the [GeoDjango Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) using Sqlite as described [here](https://github.com/Archaeocomputers/geodjango-sqlite).

When I call the **load.py script** it stops showing the error:

```
Failed to save the feature (id: 206) into the model with the keyword arguments:
{'fips': 'UK', 'iso2': 'GB', 'iso3': 'GBR', 'un': 826, 'name': 'United Kingdom'
...
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: world_worldborder.mpoly
...
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: world_worldborder.mpoly
```

**Has anyone know this problem's cause? And a way to Django manage the geometry well importing all the data including 'United Kingdom' record?**

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6.8
- Django==2.2.7
- pkg-resources==0.0.0
- pytz==2019.3
- spatialite==0.0.3
- sqlparse==0.3.0
- libgeos-dev==3.6.2-1build2
- binutils==2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.2
- libproj-dev==4.9.3-2
- gdal-bin==2.2.3+dfsg-2
- libgdal-dev==2.2.3+dfsg-2
- python3-gdal==2.2.3+dfsg-2

Answer (score 0):

I only could handle it setting the **mpoly/geom** field **null=True** in the **models.py**:

```
mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(null=True)
```

It is not a complete solution because at least 'United Kingdom' was ignored. But it was a very good workaround.

I don't think there is a problem in the TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp.
It seems there is a problem when Django try to generate the SQL.